# Weird SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working on a project and I have a weird requirement.

I have a table `A` with fields `(TechID(Primary Key), Orders (INTEGER NUMBER),Name (Varchar))`.

The values of `Orders` can be `0, 1, 2, 3, .......` My task is to display the contents of the table ordered by `Orders` field. rows where the `Orders` field has a value of `1` are displayed first, followed sequentially by the rest. rows with a value of `0` must be displayed at the end. If all the `Orders` field's values are 0 I need to order the table by the `TechID` field.

Any ideas about achieving this ? Can this be achieved with a SQL query or should I write a T-Sql script for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't actually test it, but this general idea should work:

```
SELECT * FROM A
ORDER BY
    CASE Orders WHEN 0 THEN 2147483647 ELSE Orders END,
    TechID
```

NOTE: This assumes `Orders` is an `int`. If its a `bigint` use 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 instead.

Answer (score 9):

That's an easy one:

```
select *
from A
order by case Orders     -- 1. Orders values
           when 0 then 2 --    of zero collate after
           else        1 --    non-zero Orders values
         end ,           --
         Orders ,        -- 2. Then collate by Orders value proper
         TechID          -- 3. Then by TechID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement in the ORDER BY clause. The secondary sort by TechID will take care of your requirement to sort by TechID when all Orders values are 0.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
ORDER BY
   Case
      When (Orders = 0) Then 9999
      Else   Orders
   End,
   TechID
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it will work on databases other then oracle's

SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY orders nulls last